# Get top values of multiple group bys

Tags: r, dplyr

I've been trying a few ways to achieve (`do`, `row_number`) this but still stuck.

I have 3 groups: month, city, and gender.

I would like to get only the top 5 count of these 3 group bys.

This code works fine only with 2 groups:

```
df_top5_2grp <- df %>%
            group_by(month, city) %>%
            tally() %>%
            top_n(n = 5, wt = n) %>%
            arrange(retention_month, desc(n))
```

However, it won't return the top 5 count if I add an additional group:

```
df_top5_3grp <- df %>%
            group_by(month, city, gender) %>%
            tally() %>%
            top_n(n = 5, wt = n) %>%
            arrange(retention_month, gender, desc(n))
```

It returns all rows instead. The only difference is I added `gender`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible data to verify the output.

Comment: Can't you provide a little bit of your data frame?

Comment: The code here looks like it finds all combinations of month/city/gender, and within each combination identifies the top 5. It sounds possible that you might have 5 or fewer rows for each combination of month/city/gender, which will return all your rows.  Are you looking for something different?

Comment: Perhaps there are no repeating rows for each combination of those 3 groups. But without access to (at least some) your data, that's only a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need an `ungroup()` in there.

In the first example below, it returns all the rows, since there are 7 groups, each with one row. So returning the top 5 of each of the seven groups returns all rows.

```
 mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%    # grouping across three variables
   tally() %>%                  # tally is a summarization that removes the last grouping
   top_n(n = 5, wt = n)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
# Groups:   cyl, vs [5]      # NOTE! This reminds us the data is still grouped
    cyl    vs    am     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     0     1     1
2     4     1     0     3
3     4     1     1     7
4     6     0     1     3
5     6     1     0     4
6     8     0     0    12
7     8     0     1     2
```

Adding ungroup makes it so the top 5 filtering happens across all the summarized groups, not within each group.

```
 mtcars %>%
   group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
   tally() %>% 
   ungroup() %>%
   top_n(n = 5, wt = n)
# A tibble: 5 x 4
    cyl    vs    am     n
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>
1     4     1     0     3
2     4     1     1     7
3     6     0     1     3
4     6     1     0     4
5     8     0     0    12
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, i need the top 5 `within each group` in this case

Comment: We need some example data and expected output to understand the issue. When you say "top five across all the summarized groups," the expected behavior of top_n is to provide 5 rows of output. How many are you looking for?